# Meteor callbacks returning undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

So I've recently started using Meteor.js, and although I appreciate its power, I'm having some issues with the way some of it works. I have a very basic couple of functions that I'm trying to use to get the hang of returning data to the client.

In my server folder:

```
Meteor.methods({
"thing": (number) => {
    return number;
}
});
```

And then when it is used:

```
const five = Meteor.call("thing", 5);
console.log(five);
```

But all I get is `undefined`

This is so basic, I assume I must have a fundamental misunderstanding about how this process is supposed to work. I have tried reading up on similar questions, but they mostly reference asynchronous processes, whereas this shouldn't wait on anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

any communication from client to server is asynchronous, including Meteor methods. you're using a synch return value, which isn't what you're expecting.

make it more like this:

```
    Meteor.call('thing', function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            alert(error);
            return;
        }

        console.log(result);
    });
```

Comment: thank you so much. That was my fundamental misunderstanding. It works now.